# No data in rails 3 access.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

One of the log files that i used regularly on my last server was the rails access.log

On our new host the file isn't supplying any data. I did a search and couldn't find any reference to the file. I'm wondering if needs to be configured and/or whether there are specific ownership/permission settings on the file that need to be in place.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access.log is usually written by the web server, not Rails.  Check the apache or nginx or whatever config to find out where it's writing it.  My guess is you're used to it being configured to be written in the same place as your rails logs, but now it isn't.